# How to make crispy chocolate?

Tags: chocolate

I tried to make crispy chocolate using dark compound outer casing. An inner filling made of dark compound, fresh cream, honey mixture along with some rice crisps.

But the crisps end up loosing crispiness and starts becoming chewy in a bad way.

How can i maintain the crispiness of rice crisps in my chocolate. Also please advice other ways to make crunchy and crispy chocolate at home.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Seasoned Advice! To be more helpful, can you include 1) The full recipe if possible (ratios of ingredients and prepartion method) and 2) How you store it. Additionally, this forum is about problem solving, so please edit your question to give us a clear goal - do you want us to help you with the current recipe or do you want different recipes? Mind that recipe requests are off topic according to community guidelines [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: it sounds like the moisture of the filling is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to temper your chocolate first. Tempering causes the cocoa butter molecules to settle in the correct configuration to produce snappy firm chocolate at room temperature. Try [this approach](https://sortedfood.com/article/temper-chocolate-the-sorted-way).

Comment: Are you sure you are addressing the actual concern in the question? It seems that the OP is aiming to make not a bar of chocolate that "snaps" on its own, but a piece of chocolate with rice crisps embedded, like [this](https://www.rosalindcandy.com/products/chocolate-bar-crisp-rice), and the crisps are getting soggy.

Comment: I think it would definitely help the overall crispiness of the bar. The only other thing I can think of would be to toss the rice crispies in some sort of stabilizing sugar/starch mixture (candying them) beforehand and then dry them thoroughly in an attempt to make them more water resistant prior to adding them to the chocolate. Chocolate actually contains very little water (it’s primarily cocoa butter and cocoa solids) therefore if it’s not crunchy that implies that the cocoa butter is not in the proper configuration, not that the crispies are wet.